# ArrayList<string> add item in pre last position

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I try to create an ArrayList with fixed last item.
For example, in the ArrayList `[0,1,2,last]`, I am trying to add an item in the second last position instead of last one. So, if i want to add a new item(say `3`) before `last` and i do something like `arraylist.add(3)` then it will give output `[0,1,2,last,3]` which is clearly not my requirement. Can any tell me how to do it?

Comment: Yes, it can definitely be done - look through the documentation of `ArrayList` and you should find the relevant method pretty quickly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [add(int index,
       E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) method.

Here is an example:

```
list.add(list.size() - 1, 3);
```

Comment: Again, only if list.size() > 0

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this way, which handle if array's size is zero.

```
arraylist.add( (arraylist.size() == 0 ? 0:arraylist.size()-1), object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), that inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

```
arraylist.add(arraylist.size()-1, 3);
```

Insert your value to the end that is `arraylist.size()` and minus 1 as the pre-last position.

Answer (score 1):

You can add like this to address your problem:

```
arraylist.add(arraylist.size()-1,3)
```

It will add the value in `arraylist.size()-1`th position in the arrayList.